# (How) can I create PyCharm global parameters for Run/Debug configurations?

Tags: pycharm

I use PyCharms run/debug configurations a lot. Can I somewhere store global parameters that I otherwise would need to adjust in many many configuration parameter fields? Things like paths etc...

For example, I have some python configurations that point to a script and I hand over some parameteres in the parameter field.

`-param1 some\path\somewhere -param2 ALL -param3 some\other\path`

These params will be identical in many scripts so it would be great to store them somewhere like:

```
deploy_path = some\path\somewhere
data_path = some\other\path
```

so I can do:
`-param1 {dpeloy_path} -param2 ALL -param3 {data_path}`

The curly braces just as an idea of course. several parameters in multiple configurations will have to be updated simultaneously. Instead of having to edit every single one I would like to store this common information somewhere else where I can edit it in one place.

Comment: can you please update the question with an example about how would you like to use such "global parameters" ?

Comment: yes, of course!

Comment: Can you please further explain your problem, I mean by including the steps that you are doing manually and that you would like to automate?

Comment: several parametes in multiple configurations will have to be updated simultenously. Instead of having to edit every single one I would like to store this common information somewhere else where I can edit it in one place.